# Proof of Theorem 9.2 of the book Cubic Forms by Yu. I. Manin (end of page 37)

Tags: gr.group-theory, notation

I warn that I first posted this question in Mathematics Stack Exchange but it got no attention at all. I think that it fits better there by its explanatory nature but maybe the book being reference is too advanced for that site.

In the mentioned [book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/cubic-forms/manin/978-0-444-87823-6) there is some notation that it is not well introduced (or at least I missed it). The point is that Manin uses curly brackets to represent the group generated by a subset of elements of a group or an element itself. Thus, if $G$ is a group, $A\subseteq G$ is a subset and $x\in G$ is an element, then, for Manin, $\{A\}$ is the subgroup generated by the elements in $A$ and $\{x\}$ is the subgroup generated by the element $x.$ However, in the page 37 he begins to do a strange use of parentheses around elements or sets. It seems that by $(x)$ he means just the set $\{x\}$ that he cannot denote like that because of his (unfortunate) use of the curly brackets to represent generation. And then at the end of that page he literally writes that under certain hypotheses we would have that the set of generators "$E=(N)\smallsetminus(1)$." What does this last expression mean? $N$ is itself a group so I do not understand what is the meaning of these parentheses. Additionally, what is exactly the contradiction reached in that las line of page 37? I hope that someone can illuminate me on understanding that notation and that contradiction.

Comment: Why not ask Manin?

Comment: @dodd This is very good suggestion actually. I did not think about this because I thought that, being 84 yo, he was no longer reachable through Academia but surprisingly I just saw that he still has his mail in the Max Planck at Bonn though I do not know if he is still answering. I suppose he does!

Comment: I can't find your m.se post. Did you delete it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I did to avoid duplicities. Sorry.

Comment: You mean *duplication*. But the way to avoid duplication is to keep both posts up but with a link in each to the other. That way, people can easily check to see what's been done, and avoid duplication.

Comment: @GerryMyerson As I said, the post got no attention at all. That mean no votes, no answers and no comments so nothing important has been deleted. I see the point in linking the questions when any version has something in it. In this case the deleted question had nothing at all, as I warned at the beginning. Oh, and sorry for the archaic word used!

Comment: "Duplicity" isn't archaic, it just doesn't mean "duplicate". The point of leaving the m.se post up & linked to this one, even if there's nothing there but the original post, is that you never know when someone may stumble across it and be interested enough to follow the link here.